# Prevent JQuery Timepicker from displaying using beforeShow

Tags: php, jquery, timepicker

I'm trying to find out the solution of this one but I am not able to find anything yet.There is beforeShow properties for timepicker. What I want to achieve is, before showing up the timepicker I want to do some validation. If the validation is passed, then the timepicker will come up, but if it is fail, then the timepicker will not pop up. How can I achieve this? I tried to put

```
beforeShow: function(){return false},
```

but nothing happens

EDIT:

I came across a solution said that remove that field and replace with a new one. Tt works, the timepicker is not showing up anymore. But, if the validation is passed, that field must can be used again. Now i can't. It seems like the text field is not replace with the correct one. Because when I alert the parentNode, it is getting the `<td>` node, not the `<form>` node. I put that form in the table. My JS code:

```
$('input[id^=timepicker]').timepicker({beforeShow: function(instant){

        if(!validation){ //validation fail
            var element = document.getElementById(instant.id);
            var clonedElement = element.cloneNode(true);
            var parentElement = element.parentNode;
            parentElement.replaceChild(clonedElement, element);
        else{
            $("#"+instant.id).timepicker();
        }
    }

});
```

My HTML is like

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="timepicker1" name="tp" readonly="true"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trt this ;

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    beforeShow: function(){
                    var validation = true;
                    if(validation){
                        $.timepicker.hide();
                       //this one should not be display since there is an error
                    }

                }
});
```

Comment: if you dont think its  a time waste process ,please create fiddle for that ..so that others can also dig into the problem

Comment: just noticed even I put the one that I had edited, the timepicker still keep coming at the top of the page. How to catter this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i am using timepicker,not datepicker..i can see that you put datepicker..

Comment: I just found out a solution, without using beforeShow, I try to use onSelect, so when the user select the time, I can do the validation after that..not a better option in term of usability, but this is what i can do i think..

Comment: you can do the same for time picker also like this  ...http://jsfiddle.net/zW9XR/27/

Comment: I want to put an alert to tell the error message to the user.. when i put an alert in the fiddle, the alert pops up so many time..

Comment: In my browser, the alert keep coming for several times, may I know why?

Comment: my console says Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Timepicker> has no method 'hide' fiddle.jshell.net:108
$.timepicker.beforeShow fiddle.jshell.net:108
$.extend._showTimepicker jquery.ui.timepicker.js:334
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i

Comment: put the alert after hide the timepicker

Comment: To show the functionality to you , fiddle is the only way ..its working there fine ..so i am unable to help you further ..sorry for that ..

Comment: It is ok,thank you so much.. i found a better way..I altered the callback function when displaying the hour and minute so that I can get rid more of the validation.. Thank you for all your comments and helps...

Comment: Its ok.cheers..great to hear that you resolved that. :) congos.